# spresenseでNMEA文字列を扱いたい

Tags: spresense

GNSSのArudinoサンプル[2.6. QZSS 災危通報を出力する]で、
gpsutils/cxd56_gnss_nmea.hを用いて、
NMEAライブラリ経由で、
NMEA_Output(&(((GnssPositionData*)PositionData)->Data))部分でNMEAセンテンスを出力してるようですが、
内部の処理及びコードについて教えていただけないでしょうか。
ヘッダファイルのみで内部の処理が記載されたファイルが見当たらなかったため、質問させていただきました。

Answer (score 0):

実体は、Arduinoパッケージ内にあるspresense-sdkライブラリ(Arduino15/packages/SPRESENSE/tools/spresense-sdk)の中に含まれているようです。また、興味があったのでSpresense SDKの中もみてみましたが、NMEA_Output()関数はライブラリのかたちで提供されているみたいです。